# Is there an alternative for \begin{figure} to caption diagrams in tikzcd?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, tikz-cd

I am writing my thesis at the moment and I need a few diagrams inside a Theorem. At the moment I am using tikzcd and figure, but my diagrams always jump to the beginning of my page. Is there a better alternative than figure to use inside a Theorem or is there a way to get my tikzcd centered with a caption inside the Theorem?

```
\begin{theorem}
 \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
    \mathcal L \ar[d,"\iota", swap]
    \ar[r,"j" color = black]& T(L)  
     \ar[dl,"\pi " color = black]   
    \\
  \mathcal U
  \end{tikzcd}
    \caption{Einbettung}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{theorem}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you want a captioned figure as the statement of a theorem?

Comment: Well, mostly it is a diagram inside a Lemma and I want to prove that it is true. So why not put a captioned diagram at the end of the Lemma ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a captions outside floats (`figure`, `table`, etc.) by using the `\captionof` command provided by the `caption` package.

```
\usepackage{caption}
...
\captionof{figure}{Einbettung}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works and I can just use \begin{center} and then it works! :)